# Laravel unique validation for multiple values from tags input

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I need to use laravel unique validation over tags inputs,but i face issue with multiple values ,the unique rule working well when insert one value, but when add more than one value it does't work .

this my controller code

```
 public function createteacher()
 {
     $rules = array (
         'teacher-name'  => 'required|unique:teacher,name',
     );

     $msgs =array(
         'teacher-name.required' => 'please insert teacher name',  
         'unique' => 'teacher name already exist',
     );

     $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules,$msgs);

     if ($validator->fails())
     {
         return  Response::json(['success'=>false,'error'=>$validator->errors()->toArray() ]);
     }
     else
     {
         $c = count(explode(',', Input::get('teacher-name')));

         $teachers_ids = explode(',', Input::get('teacher-name'));

         //if Validated
         for ($i = 0 ; $i < $c ; $i++)
         {
             $new_teacher = Teacher::firstOrCreate(array('name'=>$teachers_ids[$i]));  
         }

         return Response::json(['success'=>true]); 
     }
 }
```

and this my view code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="box box-redorange">
  <div class="box-header">
   <h3 class="box-title" style="float:right"> Adding Teachers </h3>
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg" style="display:none float:left;" id="teacher-adding-load"></i> &nbsp;
   </div>
  <div class="box-body">                                    

     {{Form::open(array('url'=>'management/createteacher','id'=>'teacher-form'))}}
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="teacher-name[]">Teacher Name </label>
    <select multiple data-role="tagsinput" name="teacher-name[]"   id="teacher-name" class="form-control" autofocus="true">
           <option value="" ></option>
    </select>
      </div>                     
      </div> <!-- end box body-->
      <div class="box-footer">
      {{Form::submit('Add',array('style'=>'color:#fff;font-weight:bold; ','class' => 'btn btn-redorange btn-block btn-sm')) }}
       {{Form::close()}}
       </div> <!--end box footer -->
       </div> <!-- end box -->
       <div class="form-group help-block teahcer-form-msgs" style="display:none;">
             <small></small>
       </div> 
      </div> <!-- end col-m-6 -->
```

finally my ajax code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 var msgs = $('.teahcer-form-msgs');

 $('#teacher-form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 var $teacher_loading = $('#teacher-adding-load').show();

   // form data
    var formData = new FormData ();

     formData.append('teacher-name' , $('#teacher-name').val());

 $.ajax({
 url:'/elaqsacenter/public/management/createteacher',
 method:'post',
 processData:false,
 contentType:false,
 cache:false,
 dataType: 'json',
 data:formData,
 complete:  function(){
      $teacher_loading.hide();
  },
   global: false,
   success:function(data){

   msgs.hide().find('small').empty();

   if (!data.success) {

    $.each(data.error,function(index,error){

        msgs.find('small').append('<p class="text-danger">'+'<span     

       class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true">

       </span>'+' '+error+'</p>');

      // disable submit button when throw Validation messages 
     $('input[type=submit]').prop("disabled", true);
       setTimeout(function() {
       $('input[type=submit]').prop("disabled", false);
      }, 4000);
  });
    msgs.slideDown();
    msgs.delay(3000).slideUp();

  }else{
 msgs.find('small').append('<p class="text-success">data Inserted</p>');
      msgs.slideDown();
      msgs.delay(3000).slideUp();
      setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},2000);  
   }

 },
  global: false,
  error:function(){},

   });

  });

});
```

**My main question how i can use Unique Rule with multiple value inserted by tags input**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found more simple way can loop over tagsInput values to validate it as below

```
   $c = count(Input::get('teacher-name') );

    //In view the name must be  name="teacher-name[]"
   $teacher_name =Input::get('teacher-name');

   /* To loop over multiple values that insert from tags input.
      you can add all laravel validation with this way .
      and custom :attribute by setAttributeNames() method */      
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c ; $i++){

   $rules[$i] = 'required|between:3,15';

   $customAttributes[$i] =  $i + 1  ;
}

    $msgs =  array('required' => '.Teacher Name Is Required' ,
                   'between' => '.Teacher Num  (:attribute) must be between 3 : 15 chars' ) ; 

    $validateTeacher = Validator::make($teacher-name,$rules,$msgs);
    $validateTeacher->setAttributeNames($customAttributes); 

      if ($validateDivision->fails() OR $validateGrade->fails()) 
    {
       // return Ajax Validation Messages OR laravel Validation Messages 
    }
```

By the above way you can loop over tagsInput values one by one, Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. The thing is that you are submitting an array [] `teacher-name[]`. Given that, let's say after submitting you can output the whole array you've got by typing the following:

```
$data=Input::all();
            echo '<p style="color: blue;">The array data submitted are :<br><strong>'.print_r(Input::all(),true).'</strong></p>';
            die();
```

You will notice that you are actually getting an array inside an array. So the validation expects an array of values, and not an array of arrays.

To solve this, you need to use a foreach function. Just for testing purposes, let's say the teacher's name should not be greater than 5 characters long:

```
    $data=Input::all();
                echo '<p style="color: blue;">The array data submitted are :<br><strong>'.print_r(Input::all(),true).'</strong></p>';
foreach ($data['teacher-name'] as $key => $value) {
$validacion=Validator::make(
                        array(
                            $key    =>  $value
                            ),
                        array(
                            $key    =>  'max:5'
                            ),
                        array(
                            'max'   => 'In Spanish i\'d say this field can\'t be greater than :max chars...'
                            )
                        );
                    if($validacion->fails()){
                        echo '<p style="color: red;">Validation has failed for <b>'.$value.'</b></p>';
                    }
}
            die();
```

So, the solution is that you have to use a foreach function when submitting an array of arrays for `Input::all()`.

Comment: thanks pathros for your answer , please see my answer maybe to be useful . thanks again

Comment: @JustUser Yeah, it is useful! Thanks :) ☺